# xUnit cannot test DbConnection Type with IsType

Tags: c#, xunit

I am writing an xUnit test for my connectionFactory. like so:

```
namespace Common.Tests.Services
{
    public class DBConnectionFactoryTest : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration testConfig;
        private DBConnectionFactory testDBConnectionFactory;
        private DbConnection testDBConnection;

       public DBConnectionFactoryTest()
        {
            // Read the configuration
            testConfig = new TestConfigurator().Configuration;
        }
        [Fact]
        public void ShouldConnect()
        {
            //Arrange
            testDBConnectionFactory = new DBConnectionFactory(testConfig);

            //Act
            testDBConnection = testDBConnectionFactory.CreateConnection();

            //Assert
            Assert.IsType<DbConnection>(testDBConnection);
            Assert.IsType(typeof(DbConnection),testDBConnection);
            Assert.IsType(DbConnection,testDBConnection);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            testDBConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

It continues to complain that I cannot test against `DbConnection`. I want to test that a `DbConnection` was  established. It is asking me to change it to `IsAssignablefrom` but that does not seem to be the same as I want.
I don't want to just have the test be successful without assurance that the connection was established. 
Also is it enough to test this or should I actually open the connection to be sure?

Comment: DbConnection is implementation details, you don't need to test it explicitly, better write test which will read or write something to actual database. Such test provide much more feedback than explicitly testing every possible class.

Comment: I am changing a project to move from SQL Authentication to AccessToken based authentication. So the impact is big. I wanted to be able to test the factory before changing all connections.

Comment: Testing full pipeline of your application, will provide much more value for you changing. Tests which cover original behaviour, will prove that your change didn't break original behaviour.

Comment: What does CreateConnection do? Does it try to "open" the connection? If that's the case, your test should make sure it can still open the connection after changing authentication. Also depending on whether this is a readonly/ writable connection, your tests should cover select/update behaviors too.